# Socket reading strategy in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a project where I will receive data from a TCP port, I need to be constantly waiting to check if I receive data.

My code for now is:

```
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,8000));

        while(true){
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            InputStream inFromClient = socket.getInputStream();

            while(true){
                int i = inFromClient.read();

                System.out.println("data = " + i);
                l++;                
            }
```

I don't like this strategy based in while(true), There is some strategy to receive data from a callback or something similar?

Comment: Have you considered NIO? It works kinda "callbackish" ...

Comment: can you provide me some example of a working client socket reader?

Comment: Google can. Just type in "Java NIO socket" - you'll have plenty tutorials right there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java File I/O (Featuring NIO.2). Please follow the link for sample

https://github.com/dublintech/async_nio2_java7_examples/blob/master/echo-nio2-server/src/main/java/com/alex/asyncexamples/server/AsyncEchoServer.java